# Automation tool to detect unused or redundant code in Android

Tags: java, android, testing

We are currently working on releasing an Android application to the Google Play Store before which we are planning to do performance test for our application to detect unused and redundant code.

Like for instance, consider the following code snippet as an example

```
 double x = sqrt(2); 
 if (x > 5) 
 {
   doStuff();
 }
```

Is there any testing tool in the market that goes through the source code and helps identify such blocks of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do static code analysis of your code using libraries like Findbugs, PMD and alternatively you can use Sonar runner to run these analysis on [SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com/) Server and have your results published to a SonarSource dashboard when building your code. Also it would good to have these things run nigthly on a Continuous Integration Server like Jenkins or TeamCity.

Check [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/SpringCentral/cd-pipeline-gradlejenkins) on how to integrate with your gradle build. Also you can refer to [gradle SonarSource plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sonar_plugin.html) documentation on how to configure in your gradle build script.

Sonar analysis usually take quite a while to run since you can configure to run quite a few other things apart from static code analysis, like code coverage, CheckStyle rules, etc. which may increase your build time. Hence, you should probably configure to run these analysis every nightly and for every build perhaps you can run just FindBugs and Checkstyle to run static code analysis which should be a lot faster.

Comment: what do you mean by "running nightly". Can you give some example. Also will Sonar identify such blocks automatically for me

Comment: commonly "nightly" builds are builds that are automatically created on a daily basis and contain all the days changes. Running something nightly basically means to run it with that daily build. It's nightly, because usually it's scheduled at night, when no one is going to change stuff in the code.

Comment: ok got the "nightly build" part now. Can you explain how should I go about with this process. Let's say I choose PMD. It will do a static code analysis and give me some results. So then how do I use these results on the Jenkins server or does Jenkins server include some plugin that does this automatically without any user intervention

Comment: Updated the answer with a presentation like, just try to follow that. That should answer all your questions.

Comment: hi @JugalShah I tried using PMD. But it unable to detect unreachable block lof code. It showed errors pertaining to variable declaration etc but did not show me that the code was unreachable

Comment: Findbugs should be able to help you with that.